# How to convert string date-time range to javascript date objects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, datetime, momentjs

I have a date-time range string that looks like this.

```
2019-06-14, 12:00:00 AM - 2019-06-15, 12:00:00 AM
```

2019-06-14, 12:00:00 AM is the start date.

2019-06-15, 12:00:00 AM is the end date.

I want to convert this string into two javascript date objects named "startdate" and "enddate".

How do i do that? I am comfortable using moment.js as well, so a solution with moment.js will also work for me.

Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Seems to be pretty simple string splitting to get the raw date string data you need for a DateTime object constructor.

Comment: Just use the javascript split option?

Comment: @DrewReese Yes, should not have asked this question. I had a particularly long coding day and lost my focus for some reason.

Comment: @Adam No worries, can happen to anyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code below

```
function getStartAndEndDate( dateStr ){
   let dates = dateStr.split( " - " );
   let start = new Date( dates[0] );
   let end   = new Date( dates[1] );

   return{ startDate: start, endDate: end };

}
```

**Usage:**
getStartAndEndDate( "2019-06-14, 12:00:00 AM - 2019-06-15, 12:00:00 AM" );

**Output**

{startDate: Fri Jun 14 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time), endDate: Sat Jun 15 2019 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Central Daylight Time)}

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is using new Date()

Example:

```
var stringDate = '2019-06-14, 12:00:00 AM '
var startDate = new Date(stringDate) 
console.log(startDate)

var stringDate2 = '2019-06-15, 12:00:00 AM'
var finishDate = new Date(stringDate2)
console.log(finishDate)
```